# Angular directive event not triggered in compile function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have tried alot but didn't got success, how can i trigger ng-click in such scenario where it is bind in compile function?

```
function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            compile: function(element, attr) {
                return function(scope, element, attr) {
                    element.html('<div ng-click="save()"></div>');
                }
            },
            controller : function($scope){
                $scope.save = function(){
                    console.log('save');
                }
            }
        };
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the link and $compile to produce the results you require:

```
return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            link: function (scope, element) {
                element.html('<div  ng-click="save()">save</div>');
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            },
            controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.save = function () {
                    console.log('save');
                }
            }
        }
```